# Size of block if we split 64*128 into 7*15 blocks

Tags: matlab-figure

If we split the 64*128 window into 7*15 blocks, we will get 105 blocks totally. What is the size of a single block?

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the dimensions. Be sure to use the [ceiling function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) `ceil` to automatically round your result up when necessary.

```
ceil(64 / 7) == 10
ceil(128 / 15) == 9
```

You'll have 10*9 cells, though the last block along the 64 dimension will be 4 units long, and the last block along the 128 dimension will be 3 units long. (These values are obtained from the [modulo function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) `mod`, e.g. `mod(64, 10) == 4`.)

There are other ways to split them up, of course. You could use the [floor function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) `floor` instead of `ceil` and use 9*14 cells, with the final cells being 10 long in the first dimension and 16 in the second. Or you could spread out the extra width among several blocks and get a more consistent block size. It's up to you to figure out what best suits your purposes.